# Basic questions regarding null space and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ of size $n$. We know $N(A) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : Az = 0 \} $. We know that if $A$ is non-singular, then $N(A) = 0 $. If $A$ is singular, that is $\det A = 0 $, how can we show that there must be some $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $Az = 0 $?

Comment: If $A$ is non singular $N(A)=\{0\}$...

Comment: Hint: if $A$ is singular, then a row can be made null by a sequence of elementary transformations.

Comment: You'll receive better help if you give more context. For example, do you know about eigenvalues? Do you know that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for a complex matrix, $Det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, at least one eigenvalue must be zero, so there is some nonzero eigenvector $v$ such that $Av = 0v =0$.

Alternatively, we can look at the determinant as the volume of the parallelepiped $P$ spanned by $Ae_i$, where $(e_i)$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then, we know that $Vol(P)=0$, which means that $P$ lives within some $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$. So, the vectors $(Ae_i)$ are not linearly independent, so $Ae_n = a_1 Ae_i + \dots +a_{n-1} Ae_{n-1}$ for some constants $a_1 \dots a_{n-1}$. But then $v =e_n - a_1 e_1 - \dots -a_{n-1} e_{n-1}$ is a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $Av =0$.